# How to open a program if the .txt doesn't exist yet?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got this code at the start of the form that reads a file that already exists and sets value of 4 textBoxes accordingly to what it's written inside. How do I proceed if the file hasn't yet been created? Any help would be very appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileStream file = new FileStream("cenaEnergentov.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
        sr.ReadLine();
        var textLines = File.ReadAllLines("cenaEnergentov.txt");

        foreach (var line in textLines)
        {
            string[] dataArray = line.Split(';');


            textBox1.Text = (dataArray[0]);
            textBox2.Text = (dataArray[1]);
            textBox3.Text = (dataArray[2]);
            textBox4.Text = (dataArray[3]);

        }

    }
```

If the uper is a false I'd like to proceed with normal script down below that starts with:

```
    public void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

......

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether a file exists? How to call a function? How to write an `if` statement?

Comment: How to write an if statement if the upper text is correct and what's after it is false. I've tried with if (!File.exists(path)) but to no success

Comment: When i open a program I need it to check if there's already an existsing file .txt with the data. If not I'd liek that the program starts with the predetiremend data that i have in private void trackBar_scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple if statement

```
// I edit this line according to your comment
if(File.Exists(String.Concat("cenaEnergentov".ToUpper(), ".txt"))  
 {
   // do your job
}
else
{
  // call appropriate method
  trackBar1_Scroll(this,EventArgs.Empty);  // for example
}
```

Comment: how would i call my private void trackBar1_scroll (object sender, EventArgs e)? I've written this.method(); but it says it takes 0 arguments

Comment: use `trackBar1_Scroll(this,EventArgs.Empty)`

Comment: That worked! You're all saints! Thank you a lot. I've been searching the net for a while before I dared to ask here. Just to clarify: this refferes to my form1 (it's an obejct sender?) and the second argument is empty because the previous one doesn't execute? I'd like some logic behind it.

Comment: @Aghi yes,`this` refers to your form, `EventArgs` empty because probably you don't need to use that information inside of your method.If you do,then create an EventArgs instance and set it properties then you can use that information in your method.(though it hasn't so much property :)) but you can create your own EventArgs class by inheriting from EventArgs class)

Comment: I think I understand it. Partially at least. Lots to learn since I've just started out but any input is appreciated so thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this before you open the file:

```
var filename = "filename.txt";

if (!File.Exists(filename))
{
    File.Create(filename);
}
```

This won't account for the fact that you're assigning values without checking to see if they exist first. Implementing that is relatively trivial as well.

It also appears that the FileStream and StreamReader are redundant. Just use File.ReadAllLines instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(File.Exists("yourFile.txt"))
{
   //do what you do
}
else
{
  // call appropriate method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions will work OK... however they don't really answer the big question:

> How do I know when to continue?

The best way would be to use a `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, ".txt");
watcher.Created += (sender, e) =>
{
  if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    initForm();
};
```

Where `initForm()` is:

```
void initForm()
{
  if(File.Exists(path))
  {
    // Update form
  }
  else
  {
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, ".txt");
    watcher.Created += (sender, e) =>
    {
      if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        initForm();
    };
  }
}
```